# Oracle - create_error_log - with blob

Tags: oracle, error-logging

Here is small problem, we have table:

```
CREATE TABLE "SCHEMA_OLD"."DOCUMENT_DATA" (
 "ID" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
 "DATE_ALTERED" TIMESTAMP (6),
 "USER_ALTERED" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
 "DATE_CREATED" TIMESTAMP (6),
 "USER_CREATED" VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
 "VERSION_ID" NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
 "DATA" BLOB,
 "IS_MIGR" NUMBER(1,0),
 "MIGRT_KEY" VARCHAR2(60 CHAR)
 CONSTRAINT "data_pk" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
)
```

We also implemented oracle err logging, with skipping BLOB column

```
exec dbms_errlog.create_error_log(dml_table_name => 'schema_old.document_data', skip_unsupported => true);
```

On the other schema we have identical table schema_new.document_data
during copy data, we get error of duplicate primary key **"ORA-00001: unique constraint violated"** while inserting.

```
begin

  insert /*+ append parallel(8) */ into schema_old.document_data 
  (ID, DATE_ALTERED, USER_ALTERED, DATE_CREATED, USER_CREATED, VERSION_ID, DATA, IS_MIGR, MIGRT_KEY)
  select /*+ parallel(8) */ ID, DATE_ALTERED, USER_ALTERED, DATE_CREATED, USER_CREATED, 
                            VERSION_ID, DATA, IS_MIGR, MIGRT_KEY
  from schema_new.document_data
  log errors into schema_old.err$_document_data reject limit unlimited;

exception
  when others then
  schema_old.log#write('Script_document_data ERROR:' || sqlerrm);
  raise;
end;
```

But table schema_old.err$_document_data is empty after running insert

We made sure that this type of logging works, by removing "Blob" column from both tables, after running insert we get error in table, but how to make it work with "blob" column existing?

Comment: There's no unique/primary constraint on the table in the question to raise ORA-00001. Is this an accurate reflection of the table?

Comment: It was mistype, ID column is primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a direct path insert, this is a documented restriction for DML error logging for unique constraint violations

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/INSERT.html#GUID-903F8043-0254-4EE9-ACC1-CB8AC0AF3423

> Restrictions on DML Error Logging
>
> The following conditions cause the statement to fail and roll back
> without invoking the error logging capability:
>
> Violated deferred constraints.
>
> Any direct-path INSERT or MERGE operation that raises a unique
> constraint or index violation.
>
> Any update operation UPDATE or MERGE that raises a unique constraint
> or index violation.

Comment: Thanks, after removing APPEND everything works fine!